WooCommerce Cart & Checkout Look Different?
I'm confused on something.  I have 2 different websites, each use a small theme I developed and have the same plugins (all updated).  This includes WooCommerce 8.8.3 on both sites.  However, the checkout/cart pages look completely different.  And the markup WooCommerce uses for each page is also different.
Where is the different markup coming from?  I don't have any theme files overriding WooCommerce!
See the details below...
Site #1


Site #2



This is because in one site you are using Cart and checkout (Gutenberg) Block and in the other website you are using cart and checkout Classic (Legacy shortcode).

@LoicTheAztec Thanks.  I just realized that as well.  Just trying to figure out why the "Switch to Classic Cart" and "Switch to classic checkout" buttons don't seem to work.  I'll update my question when I get this figured out

I didn't realize there was a block version of the cart and checkout.  Apparently it's been awhile since I setup a new site from scratch, and WooCommerce now uses the block layouts by default.
I was able to go into each page and delete the blocks, then just use the old shortcode to go back to the classic versions. [woocommerce_cart] & [woocommerce_checkout]
Note: there is a button within the blocks for switching back to the classic versions but it didn't work for me.
